# cannot assign to property: 'images' is a get-only property

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
class Categorycell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage : UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle : UILabel!
    func updateViews(category: category) {
        categoryImage.images = UIImage(named: category.imageName)
        categoryTitle.text = category.title
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 'images', try 'image'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `@IBOutlet weak var categoryImage : UIImage!`

to `@IBOutlet weak var categoryImage : UIImageView!`